# Conditional operator on thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

How do I do the conditional operator like this in thymeleaf?

```
Ex: condiction ? result1 : result2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Looks like it's just...](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions)

```
<tr th:class="${row.even}? 'even' : 'odd'">
  ...
</tr>
<tr th:class="${row.even}? (${row.first}? 'first' : 'even') : 'odd'">
  ...
</tr>
<tr th:class="${row.even}? 'alt'">
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: You can also keep them all in the expression, which I prefer.  Like this: `th:class="${row.even ? 'even' : 'odd'}"`